# vlookup values displayed month text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am using a VLOOKUP to look at specifically a date column on a separate sheet.

```
=(VLOOKUP(A:A,'ECRM HISTORIES'!B:N,13,FALSE))
```

It displays the date as 25/05/12, however i need to display the only the Month & Year, such May-2012.

Is it possible to incorporate the TEXT("mmm") formula?

Comment: I clicked through to your profile and noticed you haven't accepted any answers. While the members of SU are happy to help answer your questions we appreciate it if your question is answered you mark it as accepted. (Plus you get some rep too).

Comment: I apologies for this as I am new to this forum, I will go through and accept all answers i have been using. Thanks for the head sup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is Yes, though as implied by @Brad’s answer there is often an easier way to achieve a *similar* result more easily. (ie with formatting, though Date March-01 obviously will not show all four digits for the year [Custom mmm-yyyy will however]).

Formatting changes the presentation but underlying that in Excel there is still a date serial number, so 25/5/12 and 26/5/12 can both be represented as May-2012 without actually being the same, which might give incorrect results if used in calculations (in effect =May-2012=May-2012 could return FALSE).

A way round this is indeed to apply TEXT:

[image: SU571964 example]

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the VLOOKUP function in various functions to produce the output you want.

You can also just custom format the result cell with the Date format you want.

[image]

Comment: I was just giving you the opening to post a 'better' answer :).